# Add a character vector of tenors (time periods) with different units to a date

Tags: r, date, addition

I have to add a vector of [tenors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenor_(finance)), time periods, to a date.

The tenors are concatenated strings with value and a time unit, where the units are week (`W`), month (`M`), or year (`Y`):

```
tenor <- c('2W', '6M', '1Y', '2Y', '5Y')
```

I want to add each period to a date: `06/12/2018`:

```
06/12/2018 + 2W
06/12/2018 + 6M
06/12/2018 + 1Y
06/12/2018 + 2Y
06/12/2018 + 5Y
```

The vector is subject to a change so I cannot hard code these periods.

I attempted to use `POSIXlt`, but it is not working and I am not sure why. When  run the loop the answers for the new date does not make sense.

Thank you very much !

```
tenor <- c('2W', '6M', '1Y', '2Y', '5Y')

k <- nchar(tenor)
end <- substr(tenor, k, k)
start <- substr(tenor, 1, k - 1)
start <- as.numeric(start)
n <- length(tenor)

time_0 <- as.Date('06-12-2018', '%d-%m-%Y')
date1 <- as.POSIXlt(time_0)

new_date <- vector(mode = 'double', n)

for(i in 1:n){
  if(end[i] == 'Y'){
    date1$year <- date1$year + start[i]
    new_date[i] <- as.Date(date1)} 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what a tenor is, but those look like dates/time periods. So we'll use the lubridate package to convert them into periods, then add them to the initial date. Based on the data you provided, this looks like what you wanted. Note that you need a lowercase m for months (or write out months), because lubridate interprets M as minutes.

```
> tenor <- period(c('2W', '6m', '1Y', '2Y', '5Y'))
> tenor
[1] "14d 0H 0M 0S"      "6m 0d 0H 0M 0S"    "1y 0m 0d 0H 0M 0S" "2y 0m 0d 0H 0M 0S" "5y 0m 0d 0H 0M 0S"
> time_0 <- as.Date('06-12-2018','%d-%m-%Y')
> date1 + tenor
[1] "2018-12-20 UTC" "2019-06-06 UTC" "2019-12-06 UTC" "2020-12-06 UTC" "2023-12-06 UTC"
```

Edit suggested by another user: if you have a long tenor vector and need to replace all values of "M" with "m", you can use

```
tenor <- gsub('M', 'm', tenor)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base`, you could use `seq.Date` and its `by` argument. A sequence of length 2 is created, from the start date, with an increment corresponding to the value and the unit of your tenor. The second element in the sequence is thus the result of the addition.

```
# convert date to class Date
d <- as.Date('06-12-2018', '%d-%m-%Y')

# grab number from period
n <- as.numeric(gsub("[^[:digit:]]", "", x))

# create lookup vector for units
units <- setNames(c("week", "month", "year"), c("W", "M", "Y"))

# grab units from period and convert to form that seq.Date can parse
unit <- units[gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", x)]

# seq.Date function which takes start date, unit and number, select second element
f <- function(date, unit, n){
  seq(from = date, by = paste(n, unit), length = 2)[2]
}

# use mapply to loop over vector arguments. Coerce back to Date
as.Date(mapply(f, d, unit, n), origin = "1970-01-01")
# [1] "2018-12-20" "2019-06-06" "2019-12-06" "2020-12-06" "2023-12-06"
```